# Can you override the default configure help message generated as part of running autoconf?

Tags: configure, autoconf

I would like to modify a configure.ac script so that when I generate it's configure script via autoconf, it will have a custom help message.

E.g:

```
$autoconf
$./configure --help
```

yields

```
"Hello World"
```

Instead of the default which talks about fine tuning installation directories and modifying build flags.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [_AC_INIT_HELP](https://github.com/kergoth/autoconf/blob/b5832028b6d3ad087f60a72d9484b94fd6c49a2a/lib/autoconf/general.m4#L1008) macro in autoconf `general.m4` script. It is responsible for printing the help message.

This script inserts text to different [diversions](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/Diversion-support.html#Diversion-support), as listed in `general.m4`:

```
dnl The order of the diversions here is
dnl - HELP_BEGIN
dnl   which may be extended by extra generic options such as with X or
dnl   AC_ARG_PROGRAM.  Displayed only in long --help.
dnl
dnl - HELP_CANON
dnl   Support for cross compilation (--build, --host and --target).
dnl   Display only in long --help.
dnl
dnl - HELP_ENABLE
dnl   which starts with the trailer of the HELP_BEGIN, HELP_CANON section,
dnl   then implements the header of the non generic options.
dnl
dnl - HELP_WITH
dnl
dnl - HELP_VAR
dnl
dnl - HELP_VAR_END
dnl
dnl - HELP_END
dnl   initialized below, in which we dump the trailer (handling of the
dnl   recursion for instance).
```

The simplest way to display `Hello World` help message would be to just insert following code at the end of your configure.ac file:

```
m4_cleardivert([HELP_BEGIN])dnl
m4_cleardivert([HELP_CANON])dnl
m4_cleardivert([HELP_ENABLE])dnl
m4_cleardivert([HELP_WITH])dnl
m4_cleardivert([HELP_VAR])dnl
m4_cleardivert([HELP_VAR_END])dnl
m4_cleardivert([HELP_END])dnl
m4_divert_push([HELP_BEGIN])dnl
  cat <<_ACEOF
Hello World
_ACEOF
m4_divert_pop([HELP_BEGIN])dnl
m4_divert_push([HELP_END])dnl
exit 0
m4_divert_pop([HELP_END])dnl
```

It will clear all the diversions and insert your custom text without the need of including any custom `m4` scripts. `exit` is needed to stop processing `configure` script when help is displayed.

---

If you want to introduce more changes to help text you may include your own m4 script at the beginning of `configure.ac` file:

```
m4_include([custom_help.m4])
```

Copy `_AC_INIT_HELP` macro to your `custom_help.m4` script and modify it according to your needs.

Comment: I found this answer did not quite work.  See the answer I just added.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the [answer by baf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29937857/2659307), but found it caused "Hello world" to be printed unconditionally, regardless of `--help`!  This might be due to a version difference in `autoconf`; I am using version 2.69.

What I found worked as a variation that checks `$ac_init_help` and also only exits right after printing the message.  This goes at the end of `configure.ac` or `configure.in`:

```
dnl# Clear the default help message.
m4_cleardivert([HELP_BEGIN])dnl
m4_cleardivert([HELP_CANON])dnl
m4_cleardivert([HELP_ENABLE])dnl
m4_cleardivert([HELP_WITH])dnl
m4_cleardivert([HELP_VAR])dnl
m4_cleardivert([HELP_VAR_END])dnl
m4_cleardivert([HELP_END])dnl

dnl# Specify custom help.
m4_divert_push([HELP_BEGIN])dnl
if test "$ac_init_help" = "long"; then
  cat <<_ACEOF
Hello world.  Remember this is processed by M4, so you will need
to quote any string that contains square brackets, for example:

Usage: my-program [[options]] [[file [file..]]]

_ACEOF

  # Stop after printing the help.
  exit 0
fi
m4_divert_pop([HELP_BEGIN])dnl
```

Then it works both with and without `--help`:

```
$ ./configure --help
Hello world.  Remember this is processed by M4, so you will need
to quote any string that contains square brackets, for example:

Usage: my-program [options] [file [file..]]

$ ./configure
checking for gcc... gcc
[...]
```